# Wand-0.4.0 with Centos 7

Tags: wand

Getting symbol errors trying to use Wand on CentOS 7:

```
AttributeError: /usr/lib64/libMagickWand.so.2: undefined symbol: DrawSetBorderColor
```

Comment: Please file [a bug report](https://github.com/dahlia/wand/issues), as `DrawSetBorderColor` was introduced with Wand-0.4.0

Answer (score 0):

To get Wand 0.4.0 to work, I needed "ImageMagick-last-devel" from remi instead of the documentation recommeded "ImageMagick-devel"